# xmpp with workgroups

Tags: javascript, xmpp, chat

I read this document:

http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0142.html#proto-agent-states

But in no time it explains how to get a workgroup through a user or agent.

Does the only way would be using web service? I would like to use only javascript for this.

I´m using openfire and spark.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The answer was at Service Discovery.

http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0142.html#disco

Answer (score 0):

Spark isn't going to help you with this, as I don't think it has any support for that spec.  In fact, that spec has been deferred so you may have trouble getting much support for it at all.  That being said, Openfire has a couple of plugins ([Fastpath Service and Fastpath Webchat](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins.jsp)) that provide some support.

There is also some Java support in [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/workgroup/package-summary.html).

Comment: I already had the fastpath plugin and smack. But I still do not understand how to get the workgroup. I'll read the XEP-0142 documentation again. Thanks